# Why multiple selection on JList acts like a right click mouse?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlist, mouselistener

I'm adding a `MouseListener` to a `JList` so that when a right click is made, then I clear the selection from the `JList`. But I allow the `JList` to be able to handle interval selection. When I select using control button and select randomly some items from the list, then the `MouseEvent` is fired! But when I do continuos selection using Shift key, then it works fine!

Here is my code:

```
List.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                JList list = (JList) e.getSource();
                if ( SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e) ) {
                    System.out.println("Boom");
                    list.clearSelection();
                }
            }
});
```

Comment: 1) *"..I'm adding a `MouseListener` to a `JList`.."*  And that is right about the time things begin to go wrong.  For a list, add a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) instead.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I want the list to clear selection when I right-click on the list, so a MouseListener. I'm not sure why to use a ListSelectionListener.

Comment: *"I want the list to clear selection when I right-click on the list.."*  Seems pretty counter-intuitive.  I'd suggest .. **don't** do that.  But if you insist on doing so, post an SSCCE of your best attempt.  I won't help, but others might.

Comment: is possible by ListSelectionListener, ListSelectionModel and Mouse Events, theoretically (visual events on the screen) works as in MsExcell e.i., note ListSelectionListener returs array of selected rows

Comment: @AndrewThompson what does SSCCE mean?

Comment: If you follow the link I put in the first comment, or heck, if you just put that term in a search engine, all would be revealed.

Answer (score 1):

SSCCEE mean Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example. You should create one short example which demonstrates your problem. Your actual code can be long and unnecessary to show problem, so you should create small running program.

Ok, so here is SSCCE, and as expected its working fine. Let here know, what problem you are facing when you go with this example.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ListDemo extends JFrame{
    private DefaultListModel<String> listModel;
    private JList<String> list;
    private JScrollPane listScrollPane;

    public ListDemo(){
        listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            listModel.addElement("Item " + (i + 1));
        }

        list = new JList<String>(listModel);
        list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
                if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(me)){
                    list.clearSelection();
                }
            }
        });

        listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

        getContentPane().add(listScrollPane);

        setSize(500, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String [] arg){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ListDemo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: mouse events are properly implemented in ListSelectionModel/Listener